# Flip / Rotate text upside down, in both X and Y

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, webkit-transform

Id like to easy flip a text upside down, like this page is doing: http://papertiger.com/

I want to do this as easy as possible, using

```
-webkit-transition: 0s;
-webkit-transform rotateX(180deg)
```

This is my code:
HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    Js.init();
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="flipbox">
    <p id="text">Front</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var Js = {
init: function() {
    var up=true;
    //do this every 5 seconds
    var i = window.setInterval( function(){
        up=!up;
        Js.rotate(up);
        //this will run just once after the timeout
        var j = window.setTimeout( function(){ 
            //Js.switchText(up);
        }, 1000 );
    }, 5000 );
},

rotate: function(up){
    if(up){
        $("#flipbox").removeClass('rotateDown');
        $("#flipbox").addClass('rotateUp');
    }else{
        $("#flibox").removeClass('rotateUp');
        $("#flipbox").addClass('rotateDown');
    }
},

switchText: function(up) {
    if(up){
        $("#text").text('front');
    }else{
        $("#text").text('back');
    }
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#flipbox{
    color: green;
    display: block;
    font-size: 70px;
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}

.rotateDown{
    transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.rotateUp{
    transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.upSideDown{
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

As it is now, I get the text "First" to rotate as I want to. To switch the text and rotate it in Y 180 degrees (to make it readable, since its now upside down), does not work, and is why the line is commented.

So, I think I need to have the text rotated by both X and Y 180 degress, how do I do that? `rotate3d(1,1,0,180deg)` does not work like that. If I write rotateX followed by rotateY, the first one gets overwritten.

...or is the jQuery plugin flippy somthing I should look for?

Ive tried to make a jsfiddle. It did not work, but can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/EdNVw/

Thanks in advace for any advice!

Comment: Your JS fiddle needs to include **JQuery.**

Comment: Seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/EdNVw/1/

Comment: And you'd rotate both like -> `-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg);`

Comment: great, thanks!
now, how do I get the transition-time to work only for rotateX for the class .upSideDown?

Comment: ok, so how do I do instead?

Comment: here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/3ULgT/1/ The only problem now is that the flipbox does only flip a couple of times and then stops. why?